# Trying to duplicate an App Engine app: "developer does not own the app id being forked"

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm getting the error "developer does not own the app id being forked" when trying to duplicate an App Engine app. I'm following the instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/migration), to migrate an app from the Master/Slave Datastore to the HRD.

I definitely own the app; I'm the only person listed as an owner, and I've managed to duplicate other apps I own. This happens whether I'm signed in to multiple accounts or just the one.

What could be going wrong here?

Edit: I've opened an issue about this here: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8106

Comment: Are you logged in to only a single Google account?

Comment: I was, but I also tried after signing in to just the one and it still happens :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The App Engine team have now given a workaround, which is to give owner permissions to another @gmail.com account and do the duplication from there. It worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Since this issue looks specific to this particular application, you should open [a new production issue](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry?template=Production%20issue).

Don't forget to include your `application id` in the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I've reported it here: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8106